# Connecting my sql database with netbeans using servlets for registration page

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am new to the servlet side. I would like to know how to connect sql db with registration form which I created using jsp using netbeans with services, modals, utils, manager and connection parts separately. can anyone help me?

Comment: Refer jdbc documentation.

Comment: Try this: http://bit.ly/1m5p160